# Why my flutter app doesn't receive notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging when running on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, appdelegate

I have a project in Flutter which uses FCM and communication with a Back-end to receive notifications.Here some of my classes and Services:

Firebase_messaging.service.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:souhi/services/notification.service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

late int codigoSoundMode;

Future<void> _onBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('_onBackgroundMessage');
  // var app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
  //   name: 'Monitorer',
  //   options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  // );

  notificationService.showNotification(message);
}

class FirebaseMessagingService {
  final NotificationService _notificationService;

  FirebaseMessagingService(this._notificationService) {
    notificationService = _notificationService;
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    print('firebase_messaging initialize');

    NotificationSettings settings =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: true,
      criticalAlert: true,
      provisional: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print(
          'Permissão concedida pelo usuário: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print(
          'Permissão concedida provisóriamente pelo usuário: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
    } else {
      print('Permissão negada pelo usuário');
    }

    /*void _requestPermissions() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
    );*/

    

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
      alert: true,
    );
    var app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'Monitorer',
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    var e = app.options;
    //notificaModoSilencioso();
    getDeviceFirebaseToken();
    onBackgroundMessage();
    _onMessage();
    _onMessageOpenedApp();

    try {
      FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((token) async {
        await tokenFirebase.sendTokenBackendAPI(token);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('onTokenRefresh erro $e');
    }

  }

  getDeviceFirebaseToken() async {
    print('firebase_messaging getDeviceFirebaseToken');
    String? token = await tokenFirebase.getDeviceFirebaseToken();
    if (token == null || token.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    await tokenFirebase.sendTokenBackendAPI(token);
  }

 
  _onMessage() async {
    print('firebase_messaging _onMessage');

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('firebase_messaging onMessage listen');

      _notificationService.showNotification(message);
    });
  }

  onBackgroundMessage() {
    print('firebase_messaging _onBackgroundMessage');
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_onBackgroundMessage);
  }

  _onMessageOpenedApp() {
    try {
      print('_onMessageOpenedApp');
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        print('firebase_messaging onMessageOpenedApp listen ${message.data}');
        _goToPageAfterMessage(message);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('firebase_messaging _onMessageOpenedApp error');
      print(e);
    }
  }`
```

And the notification.service.dart:

```
`class NotificationService {
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin plugin;
  late AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails;
  late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;
  RingerModeStatus ringerStatus = RingerModeStatus.unknown;
  PlayerInterno playerNotif = PlayerInterno(
    som: '',
  );

  NotificationService() {
    plugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    _setupNotification();
  }

  _setupNotification() async {
    print('_setupNotification');
    await _setupTimeZone();
    await _initialize();
  }

  _setupTimeZone() async {
    print('_setupTimeZone');
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String? timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName!));
  }

  _initialize() async {
    print('notification _initialize');
    _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    String? token = await _messaging.getToken();
    print("Token value: "+token!);

    const ios = IOSInitializationSettings(
     requestAlertPermission: true,
     requestBadgePermission: true,
     requestSoundPermission: true,
    )

    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    await plugin.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        android: android,
        iOS: ios,
      ),
      onSelectNotification: _onSelectNotification,
    );
  }

  _onSelectNotification(String? payload) {
    print('_onSelectNotification');
    if (payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) {
      var array = payload.split('/');
      if (array.length == 2) {
        var acao = int.tryParse(array[0]);
        var idDispositivo = array[1].toString();
        if (acao != null && idDispositivo.isNotEmpty) {
          int disIndex = serverConnection.equipamentos
              .indexWhere((x) => x.serverId == idDispositivo);
          if (disIndex != -1) {
            DispositivoModel dis = serverConnection.equipamentos[disIndex];
            if (dis.sep != null) {
              sepService.showDialogAlertaAcionado(dis);
            } else if (dis.port != null) {
              portService.showPortStatus(
                  Routes.navigatorKey!.currentContext!, dis);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      Navigator.of(Routes.navigatorKey!.currentContext!)
          .pushReplacementNamed(payload);
    }
  }`
```

After, i'm gonna post here my AppDelegate.swift. I did everything, i opened Xcode and i added Push Notification and Background Mode. I downloaded the GoogleService-info e put in Runner.My project was built and i ran the app inside iOS and everything works perfectly except for the notifications that doesn't show up and no sound is played, nothing.Here some dependencies used in pubspec.yaml:

```
    flutter_local_notifications: ^9.9.1
    cloud_firestore: ^4.1.0
    firebase_messaging: ^14.1.2
    firebase_core: ^2.0.0``
```

I did everything and the app works perfectly on Android and the notifications as well.

Comment: Have you uploaded the APNs auth key or cert in the Firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my AppDelegate:

```
  import UIKit
  import Flutter
  import FirebaseCore
  import Firebase
  import FirebaseMessaging
  import flutter_downloader

  @UIApplicationMain
  @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    FlutterDownloaderPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback(
      { registry in
        if (!registry.hasPlugin("FlutterDownloaderPlugin")) {
            if let flutterPluginRegistrar = registry.registrar(forPlugin: "FlutterDownloaderPlugin") {
               FlutterDownloaderPlugin.register(with: flutterPluginRegistrar)
            }
        }
      }
    )
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

          Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
          print("Token: \(deviceToken)")
          super.application(application,
          didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
    }
      
}
```